# Twisted wxreactor not closing in wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython, twisted

I am using the Twisted library for network support in my wxPython app, but when I try and get twisted reactor in the wx.App's OnExit the application never closes (see below).

If I try and execute the reactor.stop() from the destruction of the wx.Dialog it works fine.  The issue is that firstly the login dialog is displayed and then the main dialog so having to replicate shutdown code and putting reactor.stop() all of the place seems really bad design.

Is what I am trying to do possible and if so what am missing to achieve this as I don't understand why the reactor isn't being stopped when told to.

```
import wx
from twisted.internet import wxreactor
wxreactor.install()

from twisted.internet import reactor


class LogonDialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(LogonDialog, self).__init__(None, title = 'LogonDialogTitle'
        , size = (300, 200)
        , style = wx.CLOSE_BOX | wx.CAPTION | wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.RESIZE_BORDER)
        self.Center()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnClose)

    def OnClose(self, event):
        dlgResult = wx.MessageBox('Are you sure you want to quit?',
        'Confirm Quit', wx.YES_NO | wx.ICON_QUESTION);

        if dlgResult == wx.YES:
            self.Destroy()

class Client(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        lg = LogonDialog(self)
        lg.Show(True)
        return True

    def OnExit(self):
        if reactor.running:
            reactor.stop()

client=Client(0)
reactor.registerWxApp(client)
reactor.run()
```

**Environment**

- Python: V2.7.14
- wxPython: V3.0.2
- Twisted: V17.9.0

Comment: What is `LogonDialog`?  What version of Python, wxPython, and Twisted?  What OS and wx backend?

Comment: LogonDialog is a wx.Dialog.  The OS is Mac OS, but seeing same on Windows.  Twisted is 17.9.0 using python 2.7.14

Comment: What version of wxPython and what wx backend?  `wx.Dialog` requires a parent window but there is none in your example.  Where do you get the parent window?

Comment: Sorry when removing parameters to simplify I deleted parent of self: LogonDialog(self, .........).  I am still using classic wxpython (3.0.2)

Comment: Backend is default to whatever it’s set to

Comment: Maybe you can edit some code back in to your question so that the example is runnable.  See http://sscce.org/

Comment: I have updated the question with an example of the issue, I have checked and this reproduces the issue exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace the `self.Destroy()` call with a `reactor.stop()` call then the application exits cleanly.

It's not clear to me if this is a bug in wxreactor or if it is a documented shortcoming/constraint.  From the docs, notice:

```
Stop the event loop using reactor.stop(), not yourApp.ExitMainLoop().
```

You haven't called `yourApp.ExitMainLoop()` but I wonder if `self.Destroy()` is basically equivalent.  Regardless, the docs are pretty clear in saying you should use `reactor.stop()` when your application is done.

Comment: Thank you, I must have missed that.  It seems a little rubbish that you can't call it from ExitMainLoop()... there must be a technical reason as you said.